# Assign a list of strings to a propertis - filtering periods and displaying the number of orders in a given period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I filter the date of receipt and cut the date using substring in the linqu question. I get a list of periods that I am writing to the list of strings.

[image]

```
 public class ChartOrderViewModel
    {
public List<string> _periods;

        public List<string> ListPeriods
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._periods; == null)
                {
                    this._periods; = new List<string>();
                }

                return this._periods;;
            }

            set
            {
                this._periods; = value;
            }
        }


 public ActionResult ChartOrder ChartOrderViewModel viewModel)
        {


            List<Orders> listOrdersUsers= new List<Orders>();
            listOrdersUsers = db.Order.OrderBy(w => w.IdOrder).ToList();
            viewModel.ListPeriods = listOrdersUsers.OrderBy(p => p.AcceptanceDateOrder
).Select(w => w.AcceptanceDateOrder.ToString().Substring(0, 7)).ToList();

          //  var Score = viewModel.ListPeriods.GroupBy(item => item)
            //  .Select(y => new { period = y.Key, quantity = y.Count() }).ToList();




              return View(Score);
        }
```

[image]

I tried to get periods and number of orders in a given period by means of anonymous type - then I succeed later, there are only problems with the anonymous type - problem with the dynamic model and lack of access to the AcceptanceDateOrder property and the key which is the period. How can I do this to display the above result and access properties? (get the above result in a simple way with access to properties).

```
public class DataInfo
{
public string Data { get; set; }

public DataInfo()
{
this.Data = Data;


}

}
```

//Controller

```
List<datainfo> DataList = new List<datainfo>();
DataList = db.Order.OrderBy (w => w.IdOrder) .ToList (); 
viewModel.ListPeriods = listOrdersUsers.OrderBy (p => p.AcceptanceDateOrder 
). Select (w => w.AcceptanceDateOrder.ToString (). Substring (0, 7)) ToList ();
```

//error

// Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Use a named type instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: I am asking for an example of how to get to the AcceptanceDateOrder property in the list of strings and how to filter the above result in linqu.

Comment: As I try to assign to the object, I get an error:

Comment: As long as you haven't received any answers, feel free to edit your question to add new information. We can't do much with your last comment.

Comment: What is the error you get? Also what is *linqu*? Do you mean *linq*?

Comment: I added the above conversion of the string list to object

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AplikacjaHelpDesk.Models.baza.DataInfo>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<DataInfo> DataList = new List<DataInfo>();
            DataList = listOrdersUsers.OrderBy(p => p.AcceptanceDateOrder 
). Select (w => new DataInfo{Data = w.AcceptanceDateOrder.ToString().Substring(0, 7)}) ToList();
```